# AngularJS Material vs Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, angular2-directives, angularjs-material

I'm a bit confused what the difference is between AngularJS Material (https://material.angularjs.org) versus Angular Material (https://material.angular.io/)?

Comment: https://material.angularjs.org/ works with 1.x. and material.angular.io works with the newer angular

Comment: Thanks @DanielA.White, our team is building a site with material.angularjs.org, but want to use the Stepper directive that's only available in material.angular.io.  These two libraries don't work interchangeably do they?

Comment: not likely. sorry i dont know much specifics.

Comment: have you looked at any thirdparty options? https://github.com/eberlitz/material-steppers

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS Material is made for Angular JS 1.x
whereas Angular Material is made for Angular v2+

Answer (score 0):

according to https://material.angularjs.org/ , that say:

AngularJS Material is an implementation of Google's Material Design Specification (2014-2017). This project provides a set of reusable, well-tested, and accessible UI components for AngularJS developers.

and

The latest update to Material Design (video playlist) was announced at Google I/O in May, 2018 (recap blog post). For an implementation of this new Material Design Specification, please see the Angular Material project which is built for Angular developers.

Answer (score -2):

@dave Hi,

for AngularJS Material, There is an third party library available called "md-steppers". We are using this one for FORM filling and Submission. Please have a look in below JSFIDDLE demo link and GITHUB link.

`Visit: https://jsfiddle.net/ipiz/vcdbuyru/2/ 
Visit: https://github.com/ipiz/md-steppers`